# Trouble with Importing Data and displaying it on a graph on a button click in python

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

```
from PyQt4.uic import loadUiType

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('EIA_20151504_v2.ui')
```

the above code i have done the following. I have imported the UI designed using QI designer and called matplotlib backend for putting matplotlib greaph in my app

```
class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
      super(Main, self).__init__()
      self.setupUi(self)

      self.RawData.clicked.connect(self.importdata)

    def addmpl(self, fig):
      self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
      self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
      self.canvas.draw()
      self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas,
      self.MapCanvas, coordinates=True)
      self.mplvl.addWidget(self.toolbar)
      self.canvas.show()

   def importdata(self):
      choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Import Data',"Do you want   to import data?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes |QtGui.QMessageBox.No,QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

      if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
          xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile('import_file.xlsx')
          self.dframe = xlsfile.parse('Sheet1', header=0, index_col=0, has_index_names=True)
          self.xList = self.dframe.columns.values
          self.xList = pd.to_datetime(self.xList)
          self.yList = self.dframe.values
          self.yList = self.yList.T
          ax1f1.plot(self.xList,self.yList)

      else:
          pass
```

In the above code, I have declared a class Main which initialises the UI code imported from Qt designer and there are tw functions one is to initialise the map canvas and other to import data from another file and plot it on the click of the RawData button.

but if you try to run the code, the graph doesnot display any content

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  from PyQt4 import QtGui
  import numpy as np

  fig1 = Figure()
  ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  main = Main()

  main.addmpl(fig1)
  main.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, ):
            super(Main, self).__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.RawData.clicked.connect(self.importdata)

        def addmpl(self, fig):
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
            self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
            self.canvas.draw()
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas,
            self.MapCanvas, coordinates=True)
            self.mplvl.addWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.canvas.show()

       def rmmpl(self,):
            self.mplvl.removeWidget(self.canvas)
            self.canvas.close()
            self.mplvl.removeWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.toolbar.close()

       def importdata(self):
            choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Import Data',"Do you want to import data?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes |QtGui.QMessageBox.No,QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

           if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
              xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile('import_file.xlsx')
              self.dframe = xlsfile.parse('Sheet1', header=0, index_col=0,   has_index_names=True)
              self.xList = self.dframe.columns.values
              self.xList = pd.to_datetime(self.xList)
              self.yList = self.dframe.values
              self.yList = self.yList.T
              ax1f1.plot(self.xList,self.yList)
              self.rmmpl()
              self.addmpl(fig1)
           else:
              pass

          def transition(self):


    if __name__ == '__main__':
       import sys
       from PyQt4 import QtGui
       import numpy as np

       fig1 = Figure()
       ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)


       app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
       main = Main()

       main.addmpl(fig1)
       main.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There were some minor mistakes which I rectified.

Comment: Does this now solve your problem? If not, it is better to edit the original question rather than answer it.